# Why is email activation useful? 

Tags: email, activation

I just want to ask you why is email activation useful. I mean when you register on a website, many ask you to activate your account by email. Is this for preventing spam, or just for websites to be sure you entered a real email address, to send you emails in the future? If it is for spam, how is that preventing spam, cant bots access mail, or what?

Comment: Should probably be asked on http://superuser.com/ ?

Comment: I think this question is a bit off-topic. Generally though, I'd guess it's both, depending on the site. Open non-commercial sites usually don't care for your email address, they just want to make sure you're not a robot. Commercial ones are naturally more interested in actively contacting you with more targeted messages.

Comment: This looks like a question about authentication schemes, so it's topical.

Answer (score 10):

EMail activation is primarily used to ensure that you're signing up with a "real" email address, and also one that you have access to (and therefore, presumably, are the legitimate "owner" of the email address).

This enables the website to be able to contact you at some later date since it now has a legitimate email address for you, the user.  This can be used for password resets, or general communication etc.

EMail activation also effectively prevents you from signing up your friend/enemy even though you know their email address, unless you also have access to their email account, which is unlikely.

This is mostly used to stop one person from registering another person's email address with a site in order to generate spam from the site to the innocent victim.  Most website's that employ such "email validation" will ignore sign-up requests unless they are "verified", usually by clicking a "secret" link or entering a "secret" code back on the website that is originally sent in the email message.

Many legitimate website users are sometimes distrustful of giving their "real" email address to websites for fear that they themselves will recieve spam from the website.  Many times, this depends upon the user's trust of the website that they are visiting.
To this end, there are a number of services (such as [Mailinator](http://www.mailinator.com/), [SpamGourmet](http://www.spamgourmet.com/), [and many others](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Internet/E-mail/Spam/Preventing/Temporary_Addresses/)) that legitimate and non-legitimate users alike can employ to provide a "real" email address that is accessible by the user, yet also disposable and temporary to allow the user to ensure that they recieve no spam to their real email address.

This, to some degree, can defeat the effectiveness of an "email validation" system employed by a website, since the website now cannot guarantee that the user (identified by the email address) is "genuine" (i.e. it's not a "throwaway" email address).  To this end, many website will prevent users from registering with an email address on a known "disposable" domain.

Answer (score 3):

It verifies the supplied e-mail address and also prevents registering somebody else for an account or mail-list.

Answer (score 2):

At least: If you forget your password, a password reset link can be sent to that email address.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons

1. That way you can make sure password recovery can be done
2. You can be sure someone will not register someone else email to spam him
3. You will be protected from spambot

Answer (score 1):

I think its for both , i.e to avoid spams and to make sure that you have entered a valid email address that you have access to

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose the main reason is spam prevention and password retrieval, but if your users do something illegal, you might want to identify them.

Comment: How do you identify user12345@throwawaymail.example.com ? I mean, e-mail is probably the least amount of identification, without getting completely anonymous.

Comment: But I just want something to give the police when they ask.

Answer (score 0):

It sure helps to ensure a valid email addresses but also helps to avoid bots that automatically register and then proceed to spam forums etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a mechanism to keep "one-stop users" away, as you have to enter a valid email adress which you have to be able to check to gain access to the website.